# Why is this query on JSON values in SQL Server using an index scan instead of an index seek?

Tags: sql-server, index, sql-server-2017, json

I have a table with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Obj1Json](
    [ObjectID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PointerToSource] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [Indexes] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [vAccountID]  AS (json_value([Indexes],'$.AccountID'))
```

where the `Indexes` column contains JSON that looks like:

```
{
  "AccountID": 73786,
  "AccountName": "5869b4e9-f441-463f-8f6d-93b4f4ff8c75",
  "ProcessLocation": "Start",
  "IsPasswordProtected": true,
  "InvoiceDate": "2020-12-30T09:00:32.8473077-05:00"
}
```

The `vAccountID` column is used for an index on the JSON in `Indexes`:

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_Obj1Json_AccountID
ON Obj1Json(vAccountID)
```

The table has about 10.5 million rows of randomly generated data (all data in the Indexes column has the same structure, however). The query I'm running is

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(Indexes, '$.AccountID')
  FROM [Obj1Json]
  WHERE JSON_VALUE(Indexes, '$.AccountID') = 69725
```

which returns 110 results. When looking at the execution plan in SSMS, I see that an index scan is being used, whereas I would expect an index seek to be used instead.

[image: Query plan of the above query, showing an index scan being used]

The query returns quickly (under a second), but I'm curious why an index seek isn't being used. Is there any obvious reason why SQL Server is using an index scan instead of a seek?

Comment: It is having to implicitly convert the values stored in the index to integers in order to compare them to your input. Perhaps use `'69725'` instead

Comment: Just curious why aren't you using your `vAccountID` column in the `WHERE` clause of your query anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that JSON_VALUE returns an `NVARCHAR` and you sent in an `INTEGER`. This causes a Convert_Implicit.

If you pass in a `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR` param/value into the `WHERE` condition, it does a seek and drops the rows read.

Comment: That did the trick, good catch! Thanks!

Comment: If it's guaranteed to always be an integer, it might be worth it to redefine the column to match, e.g. `vAccountID AS CONVERT(int, (JSON_VALUE(Indexes, '$.AccountID')))`

Comment: @ErikDarling Also good to know, I didn't think of that.